# How to detach subdirectory in Git but keep all branches

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have been following the Answers to this question [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) and had some good successes with simple Subdirectories that are only on one branch but now I am confronted with a Subdirectory that is littered over multiple branches so a simple

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter SUBDIRECTORY HEAD
```

does not do the job.

Do I have to switch into each and every branch and run the filter-branch command or is there something that can do a blanked change through the complete history ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `HEAD` at the end of your command is specifying the ref to process. You can give it any number of other commands, including `--all` to specify absolutely everything, `--branches` to specify just branches, or `--remotes` to specify just remotes. You may have to prefix these options with `--` to tell filter-branch that these are rev-list args. Note that `--all` will try to process tags explicitly, which may not be what you want. You could use `--branches --remotes` to specify all non-tag refs instead. You may also want to add `--tag-name-filter cat` to rewrite tags that point to rewritten commits - your original command will leave those tags unchanged.

Comment: Thanks I also discovered that you have to keep an eye on the output of filter-branch as it might not rewrite all branches and tags and those that aren't rewritten need to be deleted.